# Opening NSSavePanel as sheet

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, appkit, nssavepanel

I am using XCode7 beta2 to play around with Swift 2. Trying to use a File-Selection Dialog (`NSSavePanel`) brought me into some trouble.

Running the following code by clicking the associated button won't bring up the dialog as a sheet (not at all) but make my window's decoration disappear, leaving it in a broken state where otherwise functional sheets open as dialogs without decoration. Using the call to the deprecated API `beginSheetModalForWindow`, like in the commented line, works like expected.

```swift
@IBAction func openFileClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let openPanel = NSSavePanel()
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        //openPanel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!, completionHandler: {
        openPanel.beginSheet(self.view.window!, completionHandler: {
            (result) -> Void in
            print("opening:\(result)" )
        })
    }
```

Is my code broken somehow or is there a issue with the API I am calling.

Comment: `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` is not deprecated.

Comment: @Sega-Zero: You are right... where did I, why,... thank you :)

Comment: you must were confused of `beginSheetForDirectory:file:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:` - it is deprecated :)